# Junit5 test not loading application.yml after upgrading Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit5

I've just upgraded Intellij to version 2018.2.6 and my unit tests have suddenly stopped loading properties from the default application.yml

I have an application-test.yml in the test\java\resources folder, which is still loaded fine, but before the upgrade the unit test (JUnit5) would also load automatically the application.yml from main\java\resources

If I copy application.yml to test\java\resources then it gets loaded fine, but I don't want to have two copies of this file for obvious reasons.

My test class has the following annotations (which I have not changed after the Intellij upgrade):

```
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = MOCK,
        classes = MyApp.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
...
```

Comment: Is your `main/java/resources` directory (this folder structure sounds a bit odd, btw.) configured as "Resources Root" in IntelliJ? You can do that with "right click" -> "Mark Directory..." -> "Resources Root"

Comment: Thank you Stefan, yes it is configured as Resources Root. The problem has now gone after I've added spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to the pom.xml, which doesn't make any sense (I'm not even using JPA!). I know it doesn't make any sense, but perhaps it triggered something in the IDE.